# IAP: Restoring a purchase no longer for sale

Tags: xcode, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I've searched this everywhere and couldn't find it.

Apple will let an In App Purchase removed from sale be restored?

The IAPs can be removed on iTunesConnect -> Cleared for sale -> No.

Last month I added a sale package, now I want to remove but I want the users that got it to be able to restore. If I only remove the item from the app it will still show up at the App Store, so I must remove it from sale also.

So, will be users be able to restore it?

Cheers!

Comment: How are you delivering/downloading the payload for the IAP item and how are you verifying the receipt (old style or unified 7+ style)?

Comment: The IAP is a simple BOOL that turns YES and unlocks many features. All content is already on the app. The question is, will Apple validate the restore, even tough the item is no longer for sale? I added the code I'm using on the question.

Comment: There's no code in the version of the question I see here... but the reason I ask is because the iOS7+ style receipt will have the previous purchase info. If you don't have any downloads, you should simply be able to flip the BOOL based on the presence in the validated receipt.

Comment: Sorry, I was still editing. :) It's there now, sorry.

Comment: No worries; but you still don't say whether you're using the old (per-transaction) or new (bundle) receipts.

Comment: I'm using still using the old style on this app.

Comment: Damn. I was hoping you were using the newer receipt where the answer is pretty clear. I don't have a confirmed answer here, but I expect you to have trouble. However, I do expect it to be a testable hypothesis since sandbox items can be marked as not-for-sale. My code that uses the old-style receipts is unfortunately pretty complicated and for an external client or I'd test it myself before speculating.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If anyone is wondering about this, the users can restore the purchase even if you removed from sale.

The product will no longer show up at the App Store, it will disappear, but the Restore button will allow to users to bring it back.

This is very useful to hide Xmas discounts. It will disappear from the App Store, but the users that bought it will be able to restore.

Btw, this has nothing to do with the code, it is all about Apple validating the restore.

Exactly what I wanted. :)